# Google places search changes selected location address

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I have implemented google places plugin in Angular 5 Application :

I have used config code as following :

```
// load Places Autocomplete
  const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    this.searchElementRef.nativeElement,
    {
      types: []
    }
  );

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      console.log('place', place);
      console.log('lat', place.geometry.location.lat());
      console.log('lng', place.geometry.location.lng());
    });
  });
```

Now When I am trying to search something : ex- `sys` it shows list like following :

[image: Search 1]

Now I am selecting first result i.e. `Syston United Kingdom`, it gives me diffrent result than that i.e. `Syston, Leicester LE7, UK`.

[image: Search result]

Anyone faced this problem and know how to fix this?

Console results :

[image: Console Log]

Comment: It looks like the place autocomplete and place details return different formatted address string for the same place ID `ChIJGS0_tghid0gR_xM6_cQxZEw`. I would suggest raising this as a bug in the Google [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188872&template=787713)